# Wrong edit description

Tags: bug, tags, revisions-list

I just added a new tag into [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/289453/revisions), but revision's [description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/289453/2) says I added 20 characters:

> added 20 characters in body; edited tags

Is it a bug in the auto generated edit description?

**Update:**

Recently I have posted another [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291418/339911) and text for [revision 2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/291418/revisions) says:

> added 17 characters in body

but actually I just fix a typo, i.e. number of characters still same. I noticed that I made a couple of edits while grace period (5 min) after posting a first revision. So seems auto-generated text algorithm considers such actions too, but should not.

Comment: No, not a bug. I assume you did the edit that added a tag and 20 chars, clicked *save*, then clicked "edit" again and removed the 20 chars, saved again. When you were editing the second time, you could notice that the edit reason is already filled, and it didn't get "unfilled". All that was done in a grace period.

Comment: @nicael you are probably right. But I can't recall that I made some edits except tags.