# Global inbox is inconsistent between the web and mobile apps when having several comments on same post

Tags: bug, global-inbox, mobile-app

In the inbox window in apps (iOS, Android) I see 5 comments and 1 answer on screen. All for one question.

> [image: android]

> [image: iOS]

In web I see only 1 comment for that question instead of 5.

> [image: web]

Why? Is it some kind of filtration on web, that doesn't work in apps, or is a weird bug?

Comment: Actually the bug is in the mobile apps. Showing only the last comments is by design, as showing all of them is just noise: you'll see them all anyway when going to  the post. So the apps should behave the same way.

Comment: @ShadowWizard does such design issue explained anywhere in MSE?

Comment: Didn't find yet, but think it was mentioned somewhere.